# Unable to write file with Apache CGI scripts

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, cgi-bin

I want to add some logs to my CGI scripts with Perl code like this:

```
open(LOG, ">/path/to/my.log") or die;
print LOG "Some content...\n";
close(LOG);
```

However, logs are never written to my log file, while the scripts are still correctly handling requests.

I'm not very familiar with Apache, CGI and Perl, so gurus please shine a light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved: changes to my Perl script take effect only after restarting Apache. Not sure why it behaves like this because I am thinking Perl is an interpreted language and it can be modified on the fly...

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a permission problem. The script's runner (probably user: `apache`, `httpd` or `nobody`) has no permission to write to the file. However, to be sure, you need to check what [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) contains. Also try checking Apache's [`ErrorLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#errorlog) file when the script is run.

I would rewrite your code as:

```
use CGI::Carp qw( croak );

open my $log, '>', '/path/to/my.log' or croak "Error opening file: $!";
print $log "Some content...\n";
close $log;
```

Comment: You code looks good but it doesn't work either... and I can't find out any useful information from `error_log`. I suspect opening file has failed, but where and how to check the content of `$!`?